# How to retrieve a value from Firestore to change the text of button in table cell for every listen item?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uibutton

I have tableview in which there is list item and every cell possess a button, I want to fix the text and color of the button based on a boolean value retrieved from firestore, every cell's button have certain text and color based on that value only, I know the syntax to set the text and color for the button in swift, I am just not able to do on the basis of the value from the firestore, below is the code

code for retrieving the list, concerned value is checkl1value

```
func getComments() {

      //print(postId + "received")
        let commentsRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(postId).collection("comments")

        commentsRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

            if let error = error {

                print(error.localizedDescription)

            } else {

                if let snapshot = snapshot {

                    for document in snapshot.documents {


                        let data = document.data()
                        let username = data["comment_author_username"] as? String ?? ""
                        let comment = data["comment_author_comment"] as? String ?? ""
                        let spinnerC = data["comment_author_spinnerC"] as? String ?? ""
                        let fullname = data["comment_author_fullname"] as? String ?? ""
                        let email = data["comment_author_email"] as? String ?? ""
                        let commentUserImageUrl = data["comment_user_image"] as? String ?? ""
                        let commentuser_id = data["comment_author_id"] as? String ??  ""
                        self.checkl1value  = data["l1"] as? DarwinBoolean


                        let newComment = Comment(_documentId: document.documentID, _commentAuthorUsername: username, _commentAuthorFullName: fullname, _commentAuthorComment: comment, _commentUserImage: commentUserImageUrl, _commentAuthorSpinnerC: spinnerC, _commentAuthorId:commentuser_id )
                        self.comments.append(newComment)

                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Code for cellForRowAt

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommentCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentCell


        cell.commentLikebutton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.commentLikebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeaction1(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


        if checkl1value == true {
        cell.commentLikebutton.setTitle("Text1", for: .normal)
        //  cell.commentLikebutton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 119.0/255.0, blue: 151.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.commentLikebutton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            //cell.commentLikebutton.backgroundColor = UIColor?.red()
        }
        else{
            cell.commentLikebutton.setTitle("Text2", for: .normal)

        }


            cell.set(comment: comments[indexPath.row])

        return cell


    }
```

Comment: You need an array of booleans to store the values of "checkl1value". The you can do something like `if booleanValues[indexPath.row] { .... }`

Comment: @Jorge can you show by some example, exactly how are you saying this

Comment: I posted my answer below !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like this on the top of `cellForRowAt`

```swift
let thisComment = self.comments[indexPath.row]
let checkl1value = thisComment.checkl1value
```

Comment: it is working partially not accurately, for some list items it working properly and for some it is not working

Comment: thanks zeh it worked well actually both answers worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is that your checkl1Value always get changed with the value of the last item in the array. You can do something like this:

```
var booleanValues = [DarwinBoolean]()
func getComments() {
  let commentsRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(postId).collection("comments")

  commentsRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

    if let error = error {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
      if let snapshot = snapshot {
        for document in snapshot.documents {

          let data = document.data()
          let username = data["comment_author_username"] as? String ?? ""
          let comment = data["comment_author_comment"] as? String ?? ""
          let spinnerC = data["comment_author_spinnerC"] as? String ?? ""
          let fullname = data["comment_author_fullname"] as? String ?? ""
          let email = data["comment_author_email"] as? String ?? ""
          let commentUserImageUrl = data["comment_user_image"] as? String ?? ""
          let commentuser_id = data["comment_author_id"] as? String ??  ""
          // self.checkl1value  = data["l1"] as? DarwinBoolean
          booleanValues.append(data["l1"] as? DarwinBoolean ?? false)

          let newComment = Comment(_documentId: document.documentID, _commentAuthorUsername: username, _commentAuthorFullName: fullname, _commentAuthorComment: comment, _commentUserImage: commentUserImageUrl, _commentAuthorSpinnerC: spinnerC, _commentAuthorId:commentuser_id )
          self.comments.append(newComment)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

CellForRowAt:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommentCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentCell

  cell.commentLikebutton.tag = indexPath.row
  cell.commentLikebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeaction1(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


  if booleanValues[indexPath.row] {
    cell.commentLikebutton.setTitle("Text1", for: .normal)
    //  cell.commentLikebutton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 119.0/255.0, blue: 151.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    cell.commentLikebutton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    //cell.commentLikebutton.backgroundColor = UIColor?.red()
  } else {
    cell.commentLikebutton.setTitle("Text2", for: .normal)
  }

  cell.set(comment: comments[indexPath.row])

  return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks jorge it worked well actually both answers worked for me